# What timezone does Blizzard go by?

Tags: battle.net, overwatch

I greatly enjoyed the Overwatch Beta, and am currently suffering through the 2-week withdrawl until the release date on the 24th.

I'd like to start playing as soon as possible again, but I'm also fully aware that "Release date on the 24th" is in Blizzard time.

What time zone does Blizzard go by, so that I can know exactly when I can start playing the game again once it comes out?

And, even if the game isn't released at exactly midnight Blizzard time, I'd like to know their timezone anyway, so that I can anticipate updates by Blizzard in the future on the game's release.

In short: What timezone is Blizzard in?

Comment: Side note: Blizzard is based in Irving, California.

Comment: Irvine, California*

Comment: @Zibbobz I've edit my answer, but given your rep, you're fairly active, you're gona see this comment too, As of the time of writing this, the game will be playable in 5 hours (and a bit). 16:00 PDT time on the 23rd of May, check your BattleNet app

Comment: @ИвоНедев I noticed.  :) Thank you for keeping vigilant though. Hope you enjoy the game as much as I did (during the open Beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of the time of writing this edit, the game will be playable in 5 hours. 16:00 PDT time on the 23rd**

Judging by their [statements](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20100169): [PDT](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pdt).
In any case they'll be sure to specify a release time of a a specified time zone for the game.

Answer (score 3):

Time announcement on Battle.net is roughly based on the game server's region. So, unless you're playing in a server which doesn't reside in your time zone, the announcement is based on **your** time zone.

Overwatch is a bit special case; [they announced that it will be released at the same moment worldwide](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20119623). It is at midnight, May 24th on London (UTC+1; it's UTC+1 because of the summer time). Therefore, in the USA, it would *actually* be released on May **23rd**.